# Passing arguments in R within functions, error unused arguments

Tags: r, function

Consider the first function:

```
fruits <- function(apples, oranges){
   apples + oranges
}

#example#
> fruits(2,3) 
[1] 5
```

The second function uses the first function `fruits`:

```
fruitsandvegetables <- function(tomatoes){
   fruits(apples, oranges) + tomatoes
}
```

Now consider the following errors:

```
> fruitsandvegetables(3)
  Error in fruits(apples, oranges) : object 'apples' not found
> fruitsandvegetables(3, apples = 2, oranges = 3)
  Error in fruitsandvegetables(3, apples = 2, oranges = 3) : 
  unused arguments (apples = 2, oranges = 3)
> fruitsandvegetables(tomatoes = 3, apples = 2, oranges = 3)
  Error in fruitsandvegetables(tomatoes = 3, apples = 2, oranges = 3) : 
  unused arguments (apples = 2, oranges = 3)
```

I understand these errors, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to get around this. For more complex function with many arguments, rewriting the functions can be very tedious.

In otherwords I would like the function to behave this way:

```
fruitsandvegetables(3, apples = 2, oranges =3)
[8]
```

Comment: `fruitsandvegetables` function should be `fruitsandvegetables <- function(tomatoes, apples, oranges){
  fruits(apples, oranges) + tomatoes
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
fruitsandvegetables <- function(tomatoes, ...){
  fruits(...) + tomatoes
}
```

Note: *problems may arise if a tomato turns out to be a fruit*

Comment: I think the use of `...` is far more elegant and flexible than using `missing` or making sure all nested functions share the same argument names as their higher/lower level functions

Answer (score 0):

There is no way `fruitsandvegetables` function comes to know what is `apples` and `oranges`.

You may include these two parameters as argument to the function like ,

```
fruitsandvegetables <- function(tomatoes, apples, oranges) {
     fruits(apples, oranges) + tomatoes 
}

fruitsandvegetables(3, apples = 2,oranges = 3)
#[1] 8
```

Moreover,

```
fruitsandvegetables(3,2,3)
#[1] 8
```